# Send async email from IIS WFC service

Tags: wcf, email, iis, asynchronous, smtp

I need to send emails asynchronously from my WCF service hosted in IIS, after much reading I'm not sure that it's possible, but I suspect lots of people need to do this, so there must be a way. Whether I use `SendAsync` or the `ThreadPool` it seems the same problem exists, WCF does not wait for the background thread to complete before terminating, is that correct? (Not sure if its relevant but I'm calling the service from Silverlight so I have limited binding options)

Essentially I need to send emails but cannot expect the user to wait for the emails to be sent. I would hate to have to build another system that sends the emails...

Comment: I use `SendAsync` works quite well, why wait for the emails to be sent?

Comment: WCF terminates the thread before the email is sent completely (especially if it has a sizable attachment). I do not actually want to wait till its done, but the thread must not be terminated prematurely

Comment: windows service for the emails?